# Ember data commit()

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

This has been asked multiple times, however nothing has worked for me.

```
App.CatalogAddRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    // other stuff ...
    actions: {
        save: function() {
            this.get('store').createRecord('category', {
                category_id: 4,
                category_name_fr_sh: "wat"
                //... other properties
            });
            this.get('store').commit();
            this.get('target.router').transitionTo('catalog.index');
        }
    }
});
```

I can see in my Ember toolbar that my createRecord did work. One more Category has been add to my controller. But the commit() always throws me the same error:

```
Object [object Object] has no method 'commit'
```

Anyone has a hint here at what could be wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call save on the model instead of commit on the store, it's possible you're looking at old documentation, or documentation for a different version of ED than that of which you're using, see https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md for the changes made when they went to 1.0 beta releases

```
actions: {
        save: function() {
            var record = this.get('store').createRecord('category', {
                category_id: 4,
                category_name_fr_sh: "wat"
                //... other properties
            });
            record.save();
            this.get('target.router').transitionTo('catalog.index');
        }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir, I can't accept your answer *yet* (in 4 minutes). +1 for the documentation!!!!